# Convert complex nested Json to Spark Dataframe in JAVA

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, dataframe, nested

Can anyone help with the Java code to convert the following JSON to Spark Dataframe..

Note : It is not the File

logic :
Listen to kafka topic T1 , read the each record in the RDD and apply additional logic convert the result data to Json Object and write it to another topic T2 in Kafka..

T2 Structure is below.

JSON:

```
 [  
   {  
      "@tenant_id":"XYZ",
      "alarmUpdateTime":1526342400000,
      "alarm_id":"AB5C9123",
      "alarm_updates":[  
         {  
            "alarmField":"Severity",
            "new_value":"Minor",
            "old_value":"Major"
         },
         {  
            "alarmField":"state",
            "new_value":"UPDATE",
            "old_value":"NEW"
         }
      ],
      "aucID":"5af83",
      "inID":"INC15234567",
      "index":"test",
      "product":"test",
      "source":"ABS",
      "state":"NEW"
   }
]
```

Classes created :

```
    ClassAlarm{

        String @tenant_id;
        String alarm_id;
        .
        .
        List <AlarmUpdate> update;
        Get and Setter functions for all variables
    }

AlarmUpdate{

    String alarmField;
    String oldVal;
    String NewVal;

    Get and Setter functions for all variables
} 

AppClass{


     void static main(){
             Alarm alarmObj = new Alarm();
          //set values for variables in alarmObj.
           Dataset <Row> results = jobCtx.getSparkSession().createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(alarmObj), Alarm.class)

           //At this point seeing following errors.

      }

}
```

Error:

> 2018-05-15 13:40:48 ERROR JobScheduler - Error running job streaming
>   job 1526406040000 ms.0 scala.MatchError:
>   com.ca.alarmupdates.AlarmUpdate@48c8809b (of class
>   com.ca.alarmupdates.AlarmUpdate)
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:236)
>   ~[spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:231)
>   ~[spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
>   ~[spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:170)
>   ~[spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:154)
>   ~[spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
>   ~[spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:379)
>   ~[spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1105)
>   ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1105)
>   ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1105)
>   ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1103)
>   ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.Iterator$class.toStream(Iterator.scala:1322)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toStream(Iterator.scala:1336)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toSeq(TraversableOnce.scala:298)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toSeq(Iterator.scala:1336)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:406)
>   ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at com.ca.alarmupdates.AlarmUpdates.lambda$null$0(AlarmUpdates.java:85)
>   ~[classes/:?]
>                   at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>                   at com.ca.alarmupdates.AlarmUpdates.lambda$main$f87f782d$1(AlarmUpdates.java:58)
>   ~[classes/:?]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
>   ~[jaf-sdk-2.4.0.jar:?]
>                   at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
>   ~[spark-streaming_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_161]

Comment: Please update your question so that all of the code is in code block formatting so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wholeTextFiles` to read the json file and get the json text and use it in `json` api of `SparkSession` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

static SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("simple").getOrCreate();
static JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(sc.wholeTextFiles("path to json file").map(t -> t._2()));
df.show(false);
```

and you should get

```
+----------+---------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+-----+-----------+-----+-------+------+-----+
|@tenant_id|alarmUpdateTime|alarm_id|alarm_updates                               |aucID|inID       |index|product|source|state|
+----------+---------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+-----+-----------+-----+-------+------+-----+
|XYZ       |1526342400000  |AB5C9123|[[Severity,Minor,Major], [state,UPDATE,NEW]]|5af83|INC15234567|test |test   |ABS   |NEW  |
+----------+---------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+-----+-----------+-----+-------+------+-----+
```

You can use the `master` and `appName` as you prefer

**Updated**

You have commented that

> > `The way you do through file , can we do it with the object . I have to convert to Ingest the data to the other T2`

For that lets say you have *a record read from T1 topic as string object* as

```
    String t1Record = "[\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"@tenant_id\":\"XYZ\",\n" +
            "    \"alarmUpdateTime\":1526342400000,\n" +
            "    \"alarm_id\":\"AB5C9123\",\n" +
            "    \"alarm_updates\":[\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"alarmField\":\"Severity\",\n" +
            "        \"new_value\":\"Minor\",\n" +
            "        \"old_value\":\"Major\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"alarmField\":\"state\",\n" +
            "        \"new_value\":\"UPDATE\",\n" +
            "        \"old_value\":\"NEW\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"aucID\":\"5af83\",\n" +
            "    \"inID\":\"INC15234567\",\n" +
            "    \"index\":\"test\",\n" +
            "    \"product\":\"test\",\n" +
            "    \"source\":\"ABS\",\n" +
            "    \"state\":\"NEW\"\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "]";
```

and you convert it into `RDD` as

```
    JavaRDD<String> t1RecordRDD = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(t1Record));
```

Then you can apply the `json` api to convert into `dataframe` as

```
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(t1RecordRDD);
```

which should give you the same result as above

Comment: Thanks for your response ..

I have logic which will listen to kafka topic , read the each record in the RDD and apply additional logic convert the result data to Json Object . If you are saying i need to use file . I need to write the data to file ..correct ?
If yes, It will be performance problem as i will have thousands of records .. Any better solution ?

Comment: I am not saying your answer is not correct or not Good  , But it will not solve the use case that i have .. from your comment . i understood that question was not framed correctly .. So i updated . The way you do through file , can we do it with the object . I have to convert to Ingest the data to the other T2..

Comment: I have updated my answer @vss. I hope I have answered your query this time. :)